# Makefile - Generate same file differently depending on the target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I know makefile won't allow using a target specific variable as a target prerequisite.

My question is slightly different : is there a way to generate the same file differently depending on what target was called ?

For instance, let's say I want to be able to generate `file_to_generate` using two different methods that I call using `make example_target_1` or `make example_target_2`

As an example, the following code gives 2 different recipes for the same file :

```
example_target_1 : file_to_generate-receipe1

example_target_2 : file_to_generate-receipe2

file_to_generate-receipe1:
    /* some shell code here that end up generating file_to_generate */

file_to_generate-receipe2:
    /* some different shell code here that also generates file_to_generate*/
```

issuing `make example_target_1` will generate the file using one recipe while issuing `make example_target_2` will do the same using the other recipe.

The issue using this is both `example_target_1` and `example_target_2` are done without checking if `file_to_generate` is up-to-date as the name of the target isn't really a file.

Is their a way to get the same behavior and still check if the file is up-to-date ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way that it can be achieved may be with use of target-specific variables, like so:

```
$ cat Makefile
target1 target2: file_to_generate
        cat $<

target1: RECIPE=recipe1
target2: RECIPE=recipe2

file_to_generate:
        $(if $(filter recipe1,$(RECIPE)),$(recipe1))
        $(if $(filter recipe2,$(RECIPE)),$(recipe2))

define recipe1
        echo recipe1
        echo foo > $@
endef

define recipe2
        echo recipe2
        echo bar > $@
endef
```

Even though it works, I would strongly advise against such design. Generating a file in a non-deterministic way may easily lead to non-trivial errors. For example, using this approach you will generate a file and it will be checked if it's up to date, but there is no way for make to guess whether it was generated with recipe1 or recipe2. Therefore the next time you call a different target, the file will not be regenerated (since it already exists), even though the recipe has changed:

```
$ make target1
echo recipe1
recipe1
echo foo > file_to_generate
cat file_to_generate
foo

$ make target2
cat file_to_generate
foo
```

When called with `target2` first, the file will have different contents, which will be reused in `target1` as well:

```
$ rm file_to_generate
$ make target2
echo recipe2
recipe2
echo bar > file_to_generate
cat file_to_generate
bar

$ make target1
cat file_to_generate
bar
```

This may or may not be desirable, you need to be aware of such behavior.